# Run a second algo if return from a first, while the first keep running all the time. Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing

Problem description: First algorithm capturing stream video from camera and sometimes output one frame from it. Time between output different and unpredictable. Output should be passed to the second algorithm , wich processing the image and save result. While the first algo keep capturing stream video and outputting  frames if condition.

How this could be solved?

I can keep first algo running by `while (cap.isOpened()):` but it will be "paused" when output and second algorithm starts.

Comment: At first read this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

you could use multiprocessing module, then use a queue to move frames between different processes.

create a queue q.
create a processes p with input argument q.
in main process read the frames and append to q.
in p, constantly check for q, whenever not empty read from it and run your algorithm.
something like the code below but edit it as per your use case.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def do_your_thing(myQ):
  while True:
    data = myQ.get()
    if data is not None:
      # your algorithm runs here

q = Queue()
p = Process(target=do_your_thing, args=(q,))
p.start()
# your stream reading code 
while True:
  frame = camera.read()
  q.put(frame)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood the question, but I think this is maybe back-to-front. I think you are reading every frame from the camera and putting every frame in the queue which is a considerable overhead. I think it might be better to read and process every frame and only put the ones meeting some condition on the queue. I may be wrong.

Comment: i'm just showing him how to share frames between two processes. this code is not runnable, it's just a sudo-code-ish example.

Comment: Great thanks aSaffary even it's just a sudo-code-ish I grasped the idea and know what to work on now! And Mark Setchell I got me right )